# Extension working only in DevTools window

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am recreating an extension to move from Manifest V2 to V3.  Nothing seemed to be working so I simplified it to just this:

sw.js

```
console.log("Hello World!");
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "A simple extension",
    "version": "0.4",
    "description": "Prints Hello World",
    "background": {
                "service_worker": "sw.js",
                "type": "module"
    },
        "manifest_version": 3,
        "action": {},
        "permissions": [
                "tabs",
                "activeTab",
                "storage",
                "offscreen"
        ],
        "host_permissions": [
                "http://*/",
                "https://*/"
        ]
}
```

It works fine in the DevTools window (it prints Hello World!).  Even more code works fine.  However, there is nothing in the console of any page - not even chrome://extensions/ or any other site.  What could be the problem?

### Edit:

I had already looked at the answer referenced in the Duplicate Question flag.  Perhaps I should have given the more complete version of sw.js:

```
console.log("Hello World!");
async function getCurrentTab() {
let queryOptions = { currentWindow: true, active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true };
// `tab` will either be a `tabs.Tab` instance or `undefined`.
let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
return tab;
}
setInterval(function(){
    let tabs = getCurrentTab();
    console.log(tabs);
    console.log(tabs[0]);
})
```

Here, I get the Hello World!, then a promise from the first console log and then *undefined* for the next console log.  So, it appears to not find any tabs - because it is executing in the DevTools window only.  In other words, unlike the referenced answer (which says I should get the behavior I want if I close the DevTools window) I cannot even address the main browser window.  How do I get the script to execute in the main browser window?

P.S. I also looked at this, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: In `chrome://extensions` page you need to click "service worker" in your extension's card, which is shown when you enable "developer mode" in the top right corner of the page.

Comment: Yes, I have been seeing the console messages there.  That's not the problem.  I want to see them in the regular page.